# Внести одно изменение на два проекта (один коммит в две ветки)

Tags: git

Допустим есть два проекта похожих как близнецы, разница между ними минимальна, поэтому хранятся они в одном репозитории но разных ветках. Пусть одна называется `relise_pro` другая `relise_free`. Нужно внести изменения (features) в оба проекта. Как это сделать?

Илюстрация:

```
A-B-C-D_1-E_1 <= relise_pro
     \
      D_2-E_2 <= relise_free
            \
             F <= features
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ 1. Вносите изменение в один проект, потом делаете cherry-pick (если коммит один) или rebase (если коммитов несколько) на другой.

Способ 2. Начинаете новую ветку от общего предка (коммита С), вносите изменения в нее, потом сливаете их в обе ветки.